# Convert Query to Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I got this query from [Pragnesh Khalas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2456646/pragnesh-khalas), can someone please convert it to laravel query?

```
SELECT * FROM Position ORDER BY 
CASE  WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END ASC,
CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END DESC
```

i already do this but still got error message

```
$position = Position::orderBy(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END asc, CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END desc)'))->paginate(29);
```

This is the error message

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'asc, CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END desc) asc limit 29 offset 0' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `position` order by (CASE WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END asc, CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END desc) asc limit 29 offset 0)
```

thanks

Comment: Tried remove the parentheses?

Comment: The problem seems to be that eloquent expects the sort order (asc, desc) to be passed as the second parameter of the orderBy method, like so `orderBy('created_at', 'desc');`.

Comment: its working! im removing extra parentheses, now i'm having trouble with merging with 
orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(position, 1,2)'), 'ASC')

this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove extra parentheses and use `orderByRaw` method

```
$position = Position::orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END asc, CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END desc')
           ->paginate(29);
```

Comment: thanks
im using this
$position = Position::orderByRaw('CASE WHEN position_value = 1 THEN created_at END asc, CASE WHEN position_value = 2 THEN created_at END ')
           ->paginate(29);
i remove the last 'desc' because it got its own default value

Comment: how do i comment with proper way, the syntax never highlights